# Дергает меню при смене начертания

Tags: css

Собственно все в примере, при `hover` на ссылку, дергает все меню, потому что меняется начертание, есть идеи как этого избежать ?

[codepen](https://codepen.io/brezze/pen/aYdvgp)

```css
ul,
li {
  list-style-type: none;
}

li {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  margin: 0 10px;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #000;
  font-weight: 400;
}

a:hover {
  font-weight: 700;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li><a href="">Один</a></li>
  <li><a href="">Два</a></li>
  <li><a href="">Три</a></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Решение 1: Задать ширину элементу LI**

```css
ul, li {
  list-style-type: none;
}
li {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  margin: 0 10px; 
  width: 100px; /*Примерная ширина*/
}
a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #000;
  font-weight: 400;  
  
}

a:hover {
  font-weight: 700;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li><a href="">Один</a></li>
  <li><a href="">Два</a></li>
  <li><a href="">Три</a></li>
</ul>
```

**Решение 2: Text Shadow**

```css
ul, li {
  list-style-type: none;
}
li {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  margin: 0 10px;
}
a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #000;
  font-weight: 400; 
  
}

a:hover { 
  text-shadow: 0 0 .3px #000, 0 0 .3px #000, 0 0 .3px #000;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li><a href="">Один</a></li>
  <li><a href="">Два</a></li>
  <li><a href="">Три</a></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 4):

Можно задать каждому элементу ширину

```css
ul {
  border: 1px solid;
}

ul,
li {
  list-style-type: none;
}

li {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  margin: 0 10px;
  width: 120px;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #000;
  font-weight: 400;
}

a:hover {
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li><a href="">Один</a></li>
  <li><a href="">Два</a></li>
  <li><a href="">Три</a></li>
</ul>
```